# angular 1 not able to load module/controller file into view/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[]);
myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
    $scope.name = "Hello Anjnee";
});


<html>
    <head>
        <script src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myModule">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
        <p>{{name}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to use value of $scope.name in html page. I kept both .js and .html file separate.

Comment: created codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Njjaeq and it looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Did you had some error messages in browsers? The code looks good.
Maybe it comes from the CDN angular.min.js called in the head. I think that you have to put it before the script.js file because script.js refer to angular that is not loaded yet.

Also, in the head you wrote:

```
<head>`enter code here`</head>.
```

You have to comment 'enter code here' according 
the way for commenting code in html as this :

```
<!-- enter code here -->
```

Otherwise, the folder Scripts begin by an uppercase. I suggest you to write it entirely in uppercase or entirely in lowercase to make it more readable and less confusing.

Comment: Yes i did the same and its start working fine. Thanks a lot itachi uchiha

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass $scope in as a dependency into your controller.
Start your controller declaration like this:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
```